# Reversible compression and proving relation with state function

Tags: thermodynamics, gas-laws, ideal-gas

I am currently working on a question I am having problems with. I tried to solve it, but to no avail; it states that this expression is always valid for any three-variable dependent function:

[image]

It states that I need to prove that by considering the done volume work while doing a reversible compression on an ideal gas, expressed by:

[image]

and we set (x,y,z)=(p,V,T). The last derivative can be solved by using the ideal gas law.

Honestly, I don't know where to start. I don't understand how I should put up the differentials, because I don't see how w is dependent on p, the only thing that I thought of would be that the work is defined as -pdV, but I would not know how to work with the dV on itself that would be left.

I know that those are all partial derivatives and that the variable on the outside of the bracket is kept constant and that I need to formulate the function in such a way that both variables in the derivative expression appear on the right side, but I don't know the way to combine all three needed parameters. Any help would really be appreciated.

Comment: For better site experience, you can find useful [how-can-i-format-math-chemistry-expressions-here](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86/how-can-i-format-math-chemistry-expressions-here). ( Not to be applied to titles ).

Comment: $$pdV=\frac{nRT}{V}dV$$If temperature is constant, this is an exact differential.

Comment: For inspiration, use  `$$\left(\frac{ \partial f} {\partial x}\right)_z=\left(\frac{ \partial f} {\partial x}\right)_y + \left(\frac{ \partial f} {\partial y}\right)_x \cdot \left(\frac{ \partial y} {\partial x}\right)_z$$` as $$\left(\frac{ \partial f} {\partial x}\right)_z=\left(\frac{ \partial f} {\partial x}\right)_y + \left(\frac{ \partial f} {\partial y}\right)_x \cdot \left(\frac{ \partial y} {\partial x}\right)_z$$

Comment: How should I start then?

Comment: @冰淇淋 You have been a contributor here for some time now, please follow the link that  Poutnik gave you. Also note you can copy-paste Poutnik's second comment content. Making an effort to improve readability will pay dividends.

Comment: https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86/faq-how-can-i-format-math-chemistry-expressions-on-chemistry-stack-exchange